# Menu of structures

Tags: menu, tiki-wiki

I'd like to have main menu in wiki part of Tiki Wiki. It should have following top-level items:

- About
- Atlas
- Encyclopedia

Now the tricky part: I'd like to link each of above top-level menu items to corresponding structure so that hovering over Atlas opened sub-menu taken from Atlas structure.

I can make static menu like About/Atlas/Encyclopedia. I can make dynamic menu out of one structure so that top-level structure items become top-level menu items. Basically I need a menu out of structure but in such a way that it is structure's root that becomes top-level menu element. And then place three such structures horizontally.

Alternatively I could do it by nesting structures. Is it possible? And in such a way that it can be turned into nested menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I settled with "hybrid" solution. I have a structure like that:

```
    Root
        About
            Intro
            Setting
        Encyclopedia
            Organizations
            Technology
        Atlas
            Inner system
            Outer system
```

1. I created a "Root" page and made a Structure out of it.
2. Then I created first-level pages in that structure.
3. In next step I created those second-level pages - but as separate
   pages, not part of "Root" structure.
4. Every such second-level entry was made a Structure and sub-pages were created in those secondary structures.
5. Then I added each second-level page (being a root of second-level structure) to main "Root" structure.
6. "Root" structure was then declared as main menu: in Manage > Modules > Assigned modules > Topbar I added "Menu" module and set structureId of "Root" structure.

So basically it's this alternative of nested structures I asked about. It does solve my problem of having tree-structure for menu that isn't overloaded by every minute page on wiki I'd like to have. On one hand it doesn't show all the entries but on the other hand it's good - the reader isn't overwhelmed and still can access deeper pages by second-level pages that have all the sub-structure listed.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled over your question today and I hope my answer still can be a help for you.

Imho the right approach is to create a custom module and in the custom menu a "toplevel menu" with some simple html. The menu consists out of the three top items and for each one the appropriate structure menu as list element.

You want a horizontal menu, right?

The menu items "About", "Atlas", "Encyclopedia"  representing your three wikistructures would be kind of drop down (or hover effect) horizontal css menu items level=0 (to) for example in a top-bar custom module.

You hover over one of the menu items and the associated wikistructure menu appears.

Regards,
Torsten